# What is so unique about these four numbers?

Tags: riddle, number-property

These four numbers look like four ordinary numbers. But I found something unique about these four that I may be only true for one other set of numbers-- unless you raise the bar-may be.

So what is that unique property shared by these four?

**

> 1644   1646   1664   1666

**

I edited to include @Nuclear Hoagie's correct comment

Comment: Why limit to the 1600s? As far as I can tell, 1444, 1446, 1464, and 1466 also have this property.

Comment: He says 'I do not think its true' which means he is not sure...

Comment: He is not sure in the question that there are other groups he is just assuming its the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They are 4 digit numbers that contain all Roman numerals exactly once

> E.g. (1000(M)+500(D)+100(C)+50(L)+10(X)+(-1(I)+5(V)) = 1664)

> 1644 MDCXLIV, 1646 MDCXLVI, 1664 MDCLXIV, 1666 MDCLXVI

> Raising the bar implies putting a bar on top of the letters to multiply them.

Comment: rot13 Ubj qvq lbh svther vg bhg? Jung nobhg gur pbzzrag ba envfvat gur one?

Comment: I think you mean: that contain _every_ Roman numeral exactly once. And raising the bar is putting a bar on top to multiply by 1000. (And it's numbers not necessarily years.)

Comment: Yes that was what I meant